# Git - revert deleted untracked files

Tags: php, git, github, recovery, data-recovery

By accident i deleted PHP files with:

```
git clean -xfd
```

There is any good files recover tool for Windown PC to recover those files?
Or any other good solution?

Thanks!

Comment: One among others: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: A good practice with git: commit as much as you can and your files will be backed up...

Comment: @Philippe i know, but those were files that can't be pushed to the remote, my error for not saved them in other place. How i recover with this tool?

Answer (score 0):

wish its not late for this... but... if you didn't change the remote branch yet, you can make this:

```
git fetch --all // make you localrepo match with remoteRepo
```

(you can use -- if you want to fetch just 1 branch)

```
git reset --hard origin/<remote_branch>
```

With those commands you will have your local branch as the remote branch.

Example:

File = index.html

Remote branch(dev) = `<html>... a lot of stuff ... </html>`

Local Branch(dev) = `<html><html><html><html>Bugged or deleted<html><html>`

After `git fetch --dev && git reset --hard origin/dev` you local branch will be like the remote one.